# Is it possible to fetch and compare an element which resides in a nested Json string format column in database? Via SQL Query

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, spring-boot

I have 'a unique-id'. I want to fetch records from table on basis of that unique-id. I have a column named "request body" that contains a nested json string which is of type text. Is there any way i can compare 'unique-id' with the 'unique-id' inside the json string cloumn i-e request body?

Comment: With the `->` operator? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-json.html

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Apologies for the incomplete info regarding the question. BTW it is possible to do so by using the position() function inside a substr() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies, I am new to stackoverflow.
For anyone looking for the solution, below are the two approaches:

**APPROACH 1**

```
SELECT t.request_body
FROM table t
WHERE cast(request_body as JSON) ->> 'uniqueId' ='123'
```

**APPROACH 2**

```
SELECT t.request_body
FROM table t
WHERE (substr(t.request_body, position ('uniqueId' in request_body)+11,3) ='123'
```

*Note: 11 represents lenght of '**uniqueId":"**' and 3 for the following id **123***